# I hit Steam Level 8, when do I get my earned monster game cards?

Tags: steam-trading-cards, steam-monster-game

I have 16 unlocked cards from the Monster Game, but I just hit Level 8. Do I get those cards and if so, when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get them when you start a new steam monster game.